# Is it IE7 or IE8? Which will Support Browser Compatibility?

Tags: product

I am working with ASP.NET & Telerik framework I fixed issues in IE7 but I am not able to get properly In IE8.

I want know that is IE7 and IE8 will support browser compatibility?

Comment: Erm, what? No, you can't simply assume that a site will look good in both IE 7 and IE 8 without any effort. Neither are "compatible" web browsers in the strictest sense of the word. But yes, it's possible to manage creating a site that looks good in both if you try.

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/

Comment: Nope. I have to code for IE7 and up. You just have to hack it. I do the css asterisk trick for IE7. Just google search css hacks. Only way to support compatibility is have some sort of if statement to check what browser they're using and use a css that is specific to that particular browser.

Comment: Could you avoid writing in Title Case Every Where In Your Question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you go for the latest version of the browser. When you go updated, people may think that you are not an old chap who still programs on the mainframe machines and do programs for the analytic engine or the Babbage's machines.

**Instead of applying hacks that make your code compatible for any browser, I suggest you to code for the latest version of any browser. People are more likely to shift to the latest version available rather than working with the same old thing.**

And as a developer, I suggest you to [***code for IE 9***](http://www.microsoft.com/india/windows/ie/IE9.aspx) rather than going for any hacks to improve the browser support for your code.
And to answer your question, I think it is the **code that you code that matters browser compatibility** and not the browser.